# Check multiple if conditions in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a node.js app which is based on the affiliation(Referrals).

Whenever user registers on the app user will have three options which is as following:

1. If affiliation is true then save it in the two different tables like User and affiliation table.
   (eg. [www.something.com/someone](http://www.something.com/someone))
2. If affiliation is false then throw an error stating that "Please check the link"
   (eg. [www.something.com/someneo](http://www.something.com/someneo) -> it is wrong it is not in the database)
3. if affiliation is null then save the users data in the User table but do not save it in the affiliation table. (eg. [www.something.com](http://www.something.com) -> it is null)

The affiliation table schema:

```
const affiliationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    affiliatedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    affiliation_code: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
);
```

Here is what I have tried so far:
The service file:

```
exports.check_affiliation_link = async (req) => {
  var checkLink = await User.findOne({
    affiliation: req.body.affiliation_handle,
  });
  if (checkLink) return true;
  return false;
};
```

The register controller:

```
exports.register = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var isValidated = await userService.validateInDatabase(req);
    if (!isValidated)
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ error: "Phone number or email is already registered" });

    var user = await userService.create(req.body);
    var token = await verificationService.sendVerification(user);

    let isAffiliationValid = await affiliationService.check_affiliation_link(
      req
    ); //stuck here
    return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.trace(error);
    return res.status(400).json({ message: error });
  }
});
```

Comment: I dont get your problem. You dont have implement your own logic. Nor do you provide all functions.

Comment: I know what that is. But i see not a single chuck in your posted code where you implement your expected logic.

Comment: @Marc please look at the second code block(check_affiliation_link). Do you think it is capable of handling all three conditions.